# jquery tabs show only initial tab at first

Tags: jquery, tabs

i am using this script :

```
jsfiddle.net/p95nJ/1/
```

but at first, when the tabs are not pressed it whows all the tabs content. i want to prevent this and to show only the first tab at first (before anything is pressed).

this is the jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //tabs
     $("ul.tabrow li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab-content div:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabrow li").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    }, function() {
        $("ul.tabrow li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(".tab-box").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        return false;
    });

});
```

and this is the html:

```
<div class="under-slider-right">
<!-- איקונים עם תמונות-->
<div class="tab-wrap">
    <ul class="tabrow">
        <li class="first"><a href="#tab_tags"></a></li>
        <li class="second"><a href="#tab_recent"></a></li>
        <li class="third"><a href="#tab_tools"></a></li>
         <li class="forth"><a href="#tab_tools"></a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_tags" class="tab-box" style="display: none; ">
            <div class="taglist">
מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה
            <br/>
            מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה מילה  
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="tab_recent" class="tab-box" style="display: none; ">
משפט משפט משפט משפט משפט משפט משפט
            <br/>
            משפט משפט משפט משפט משפט
        </div>


        <div id="tab_tools" class="tab-box" style="display: block; ">
            טקסט טקסט טקסט טקסט טקסט טקסט טקסט 
            <br/>
            טקסט טקסט טקסט טקסט טקסט
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `before anything is pressed` you mean hovered.

Comment: when you're showing first tab content, you have to hide other content

Comment: i am, you can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/p95nJ/1/
i am using:
#tab_tags,#tab_recent,#tab_tools,#tab_popular{
    display: none;
}

but it is not working